# How to call two functions in one button but not in same click according to the value of the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button like this below

```
<input type="button" value="Select All" onclick="SelectAllCom()" id="SelAllbtn" />
```

here i call `SelectAllCom()` functions.

```
 function SelectAllCom() {
   btnValChange();
   selectAll();
   UnselectAll();
  }



function selectAll() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
   for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
     if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
        checkboxes[i].checked = true;
   }
 }

 function UnselectAll() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
     for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
           checkboxes[i].checked = false;
      }
  }

 function btnValChange() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("SelAllbtn");
      if (btn.value == "Select All") {
         btn.value = "Unselect All"
   }
 else if (btn.value = "Unselect All") {
    btn.value = "Select All"
   };

}
```

Here i want to call the `selectAll` function when the `btn.value == "Select All"` and `UnselectAll` function when the `btn.value == "Unselect All"`. Any suggestions ?

Comment: pass `this` as a parameter to `SelectAllCom` function and using `this.value`, you can conditionally call your functions further. or you can use a condition like `document.getElementById("SelAllbtn").value` and call the functions accordingly

Comment: Why not just have two buttons but toggle them or change the onclick attribute to change the function call...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, no need to maintain two separate function to check and uncheck the checkbox values, you can use `checkboxes[i].checked` with `!` sign which will assign the `true` if the initial value is `false` and vise versa!

I will merge the same code into a single function!

Here you go!

```js
function SelectAllCom(el) {
    if (el.value == "Select All") {
        toggleCheckBox(el.value);
        el.value = "Unselect All";
    } else if (el.value == "Unselect All") {
        toggleCheckBox(el.value);
        el.value = "Select All";
    }
}

function toggleCheckBox(event) {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox' && event == 'Select All') {
            checkboxes[i].checked = true;
        } else if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox' && event == 'Unselect All') {
            checkboxes[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Select All" onclick="SelectAllCom(this)" id="SelAllbtn" />

<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Bug in your solution, if one checkbox is checked, and you check SelectAll, the item you selected will not stay checked, same goes for unselect all. That is because you are setting every checkbox to be the !checkbox and not considering if a user has checked/unchecked anything yet.

Comment: @Spangle Nice catch! Fixed!

Comment: @RJ Welcome...!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type="button" value="Select All" onclick="SelectAllCom(this)" id="SelAllbtn" />


function SelectAllCom(button) {
       if (button.value == "Select all" ) {
           button.value = "Unselect All"
           selectAll();
       } else {
          button.value = "Select all"
          UnselectAll();
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution below. Based on the value do one function, or another function.

```js
const buttonEl = document.querySelector('.js-button');

buttonEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(this.value == 'false') {
    this.value = 'true';
    selectAll();
  } else {
    this.value = 'false';
    unselectAll();
  }
});

function selectAll() {
  alert('selectAll function');
}

function unselectAll() {
  alert('unselectAll function');
}
```

```html
<button value="false" class="js-button">Click Me.....</button>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Below Snippet will help you

```js
function SelectAllCom(button) {
    var btn = document.getElementById("SelAllbtn");

       if (btn.value == "Select all" ) {
           btn.value = "Unselect All"
           selectAll();
       } else {
          btn.value = "Select all"
          UnselectAll();
       }
      }
   function selectAll() {
   alert("select all function called");
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
   for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
     if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
        checkboxes[i].checked = true;
   }
 }

 function UnselectAll() {
    alert("Unselect all function called");

  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
     for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
           checkboxes[i].checked = false;
      }
  }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Select All" onclick="SelectAllCom(this)" id="SelAllbtn" />
```

Comment: In your answer, the entire point of passing the Button object is lost

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common toggle function which will toggle between selectAll and unselect All. And call that function on checkbox click.For instance if checkbox is checked then value of checkbox button will become `Select All` and if unchecked the value of button will become `Unselect All`.

```
function handleCheckboxChange(event) {
let valueOfButton;
 if(event.target.checked) 
    valueOfButton = "Select All";
 else 
    valueOfButton = "Unselect All"; 
 toggleBetweenSelectAndUnselect(valueOfButton);
}

function toggleBetweenSelectAndUnselect (valueOfButton) {
  if(valueOfButton === 'Select All') {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
    }
  } else if(valueOfButton === 'Unselect All') {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
            checkboxes[i].checked = false;
        }
 }
}

<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `onClick` in button, and no need for seperate `btnValChange()` function.

```
<input type="button" value="Select All" id="SelAllbtn" />
```

jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#SelAllbtn').click(function(event) {
        $('#SelAllbtn').val() == 'Select All' ? selectAll('Unselect All') : UnselectAll('Select All')
    });
    function selectAll(text){
        $('#SelAllbtn').val(text)
        // your code here
    }
    function UnselectAll(text){
        $('#SelAllbtn').val(text)
        // your code here
    }
});
```